# UIBarButtonItem widths are different between iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

The following screenshot are taken from iTunes U app. As we can see the widths of UIBarButtonItem are quite different. Specifically, the widths are smaller on iPhone.

[image: UIBarButtonItem on iPhone]

[image: UIBarButtonItem on iPad]

The question is how to customize width of UIBarButtonItem. I tried to set width, it didn't work and always kept width of 44.

Comment: Are you using button items with custom views? Show the code you're using.

Comment: No, I'm not. I just added UIBarButtonItem from IB, and set image of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the size of a UIBarButtonItem you need to use a custom view. Build a view with your image and the size you want and use [UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:]

Comment: I found this is the only way to archive it.